# Function execution timeout in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function call as below 
`NSData *data = [self createDummyData];`

I want function the `createDummyData` to break and return `nil` if it takes execution time of more than 1 second. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Why do you want that? You're blocking the main thread for that 1 second?

Comment: This call happens on the background thread in my application.

Comment: This is the best logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129794/how-to-log-a-methods-execution-time-exactly-in-milliseconds

Comment: if `createDummyData` has iteration nature just check time each iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create an NSOperationQueue.
- Create a Timer.
- Add an operation to the queue that does what you want it to do.
- Start the timer with a fire date of 1 second in the future
- When the timer fires, cancel the operations in the queue.

If the operation has finished, cancelling will have no effect. If it hasn't finished, and you've correctly configured the operation, then the operation will stop.

Comment: If the operation is currently executing the operation is not cancelled. How do we cancel it ?

Comment: You need to put hooks into your NSOperation subclass to check for the `isCancelled` event and deal with it that way.