# Create Execute Timer in Swift

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

Refer to this question below

[How to log a method's execution time exactly in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129794/how-to-log-a-methods-execution-time-exactly-in-milliseconds)

And I convert the code to swift like this

```
//OBjective-C
//#define TICK   NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date]
//#define TOCK   NSLog(@"Time: %f", -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow])

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var TIMER = NSDate()

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

func TICK()
{
    TIMER = NSDate()
}

func TOCK(){

    println("\(-TIMER.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
}



func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    TICK()
    TOCK()
}
```

**Timing in Swift : 3.40343e-05
while Objective-C : 0.000009
Why Swift is so slow?**

Thank you.

Comment: Did you compile both Obj-C and Swift code in Release mode (with optimizations) ?

Comment: I test that code in both applicationDidFinishLaunching in debug mode.

Comment: What are the results in Release mode? I would also recommend to check with Xcode 6.3 beta which brings huge performance improvements with Swift 1.2.

Comment: Edit Scheme then changed from debug to release and still get the same result!

I use Xcode 6.2 and wondered why it is so much slower.

When I get 6.3 I will come back to this result.

Thanks

Comment: 3.40343e-05 = 0.000034 and when I did the same thing I got as little as 2.8*10^-6. 0.000002 < 0.000009, so my conclusion is, Swift is FASTER.

Comment: let totaltime  = -(Float)(TIMER.timeIntervalSinceNow)
println((String(format: "Time : %.10f",totaltime)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use anywhere in your code and avoid global variables, you can do same approach with static functions inside a utility class like so (I call my class Debug):

```
class Debug {

private static var tickTimestamp: Date = Date()

static func tick() {
    print("TICK.")
    tickTimestamp = Date()
}

static func tock() {
    print("TOCK. Elapsed Time: \(Date().timeIntervalSince(tickTimestamp))")
}

}
```

Then use like:

```
Debug.tick()
Debug.tock()
```