# How to get CPU time used by a function in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to get the CPU time used by a function in Swift. In C we could do this by [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) function.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755558/measure-elapsed-time-in-swift) answer but it measures the real time.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Swift has `clock()`. Just import `Darwin` (or `Foundation` or `UIKit` which all import `Darwin` eventually).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129794/how-to-log-a-methods-execution-time-exactly-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `clock()` function from C:

```
import Foundation
var t = clock()

myLongRunningFunction()

t = clock() - t

print("The function takes \(t) ticks, which is \(Double(t) / Double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)) seconds of CPU time")
```