# When I launch my app, it stucks in the iPhone apps screen for 4,5 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, launch

My app is an enterprise app.
When I click on the app icon, the icon is dimmed, and stucks for 4-5 seconds.( It depends, some users report it stuck for 10 seconds.)

I connect the device to look into the console.
I found some exception is through. But no idea if it is related and what it really did. Any idea?
[image]

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when using the debugger?

Comment: no, but if i deploy the app using debug mode. disconnect it. and relaunch the app, same things happened

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your app has an issue with startup time. Apple says that 400 milliseconds is a good launch time. If your app loads more than 20 seconds iOS will kill the process. 
The main reasons of such issue can be:

- A lot of frameworks in the app
- Project has a lot of classes, categories
- Project is written in Objective-C (Swift has optimized runtime)

Try to add the environment variable `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` in Scheme:
[image]

You will find in console launch time statistics:
[image]

Also check `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in AppDelegate. If you perform some heavy operations remove them. You can measure code execution time like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129794/how-to-log-a-methods-execution-time-exactly-in-milliseconds) or precise methods [described here](http://nshipster.com/benchmarking/) .

For more information take a look at:

- [Slow App Startup Times](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/slow-app-startup-times/)
- [Optimizing App Startup Time WWDC 2016](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/)