# Objective C: Compare timeInMillis with current time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

In my iPhone application, I need to calculate the time difference between the time a message was created on the server, and the time my phone received it.

The server (Java) puts in a number returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()` as metadata along with the message.

How do I compare this number with the current time on the device? Could not find a suitable NSDate method to do this comparison.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c/889405#889405) and the [`-timeIntervalSinceDate:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSinceDate_) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(NUInteger) ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)`

Comment: But note that the "time interval" methods return a `double` value in seconds.  You have to do some (very minor) conversions to get milliseconds.

Comment: And note too that there are methods to go the other way -- convert a time interval into an NSDate.

Comment: Multiply by 1000 and type case to long or NUInteger

Comment: I can't find an exact reference for the exact time difference between Apple's 'GMT' (UT1, I assume) 1 January 1970 reference date and Java's UTC but it'll have been at most 900ms and likely much less. I guess as the author is taking the time from two different clocks anyway the difference is safe to ignore?

Comment: Epoch / 1970 time = 1st Jan 1970 at 00:00hrs.