# How to time openGL animations on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, timing

I wonder if there is a time function in apples SDK that is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing? I heard about `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` (which isn't accurate) and the c function `mach_absolute_time`.

How do all these people timing their animations in openGL ES (is there a frame independent solution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031) to timing my animation. When you create a new opengl-es project on xCode, it will give you an sample opengl-es codes, and it control animation by CADisplayLink.[image]

**EDIT**:

I found I misunderstand this problem.
   I check the **CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()** method on this [apple on-line doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001452), and it said the method may be not monotonically increasing. And the method **CACurrentMediaTime()** which I prefered derived value by mach_absolute_time(). The document about CACurrentMediaTime() is [on this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004512).

Comment: CADisplayLink won't give you accurate timings if you skip frames.

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [How can I get a precise time, for example in milliseconds in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

For frame-rate-independent time, I generally use the `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` function. It returns a `CFAbsoluteTime` (which I believe is typedef'd to `double`) since some date arbitrarily far in the past.