# How to convert NSDate to milliseconds in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

For example: assume `NSDate tempdate = "05-23-2013"`. I want this value to be converted into milliseconds.

How can I do this with Objective-C?

Comment: Milliseconds elapsed since what?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321055/convert-a-nsdate-to-milliseconds-epoch-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359977/how-to-get-nsdate-with-millisecond-accuracy).

Basically you have  get the second form the reference date (1 January 2001, GMT) and multiply it with 1000.

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
double milliseconds = seconds*1000;
```

Cheers!

Comment: `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` returns a `double`. If you assign that to an integer before multiplying by 1000, then you loose the milliseconds precision!

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. NSTimeInterval is a typedef of double: `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`

Comment: You actually need to use a double to store milliseconds, or you are likely to run into an overflow problem. 

double milliseconds = seconds*1000;

Answer (score 1):

The `timeIntervalSince1970` will return seconds from 1970. There are other timeIntervalSince methods if needed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970

For reverse conversion, I mean to say from milliseconds to NSDate,
refer this stackoverflow article.
[Convert milliseconds to NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741199/nsdate-convert-milliseconds-to-nsdate)

Hope it ll solve your issue.