# Resolution of iOS file time stamps

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

The code snippet below is taken from a greater context. I want to sort files in order of their creation time. The problem is that d seems to be in seconds although I guess that the resolution of `NSDate` is much higher. Is the resolution of the stored time in the "iOS" file system only in seconds?

The files are created within fractions of milliseconds, so I need a higher resolution. Any suggestions?

```
for(NSURL *it in archFiles)
{
  NSDate *date;
  [it getResourceValue:&date forKey:NSURLCreationDateKey error:nil];
  double d = date.timeIntervalSince1970;
  NSLog(@"%@: timestamp:%f", it.path, d);
}
```

The printout (I've removed parts of the path):
`/private/var/....archive: timestamp:1399819259.000000`

I've tried it in both "iOS simulator" and the "iPad emulator" with the same result. I guess the 6 zeroes at the end is not pure coincidence. :)

Just want to add that a valid date is shown when I hover over date in the debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nsdate with millisecond accuracy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359977/how-to-get-nsdate-with-millisecond-accuracy)

Comment: No, I don't think so. But Torino's answer confirms my assumptions that I need to solve this in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NSDate* has a higher resolution than 1 second. But the file system (HSFX on iOS) doesn't. So if you read the creation date of a file, the fractional part will always be zero.

In addition, you don't output a *NSDate* but a *double* number. So the six zeros at the end are an artifact from the `%f` formatting pattern.

Comment: Yea, I know it's a double, but I was concerned about the missing fractional part. I keep this question open for a while just to see how this kind of problem usually is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I'll solve my problem by naming the files in a increasing way, and then use the file names to sort the files. Just if anybody else runs into this.