# Objective-C - Count up/down on press/release

Tags: objective-c, counter

Interesting task: let say that we've got a counter which counts from 0 to 100.
Counting up should start when UIButton was pressed. While UIButton is being pressed/highlighted counting up continue.

Conditions:

- counter should count up from 0 to 50 in 2 sec
- counter should count up from 51 to 80 in next 3 sec (from 2 to 5)
- counter should count up from 81 to 100 in next 5 sec (from 5 to 10)

If I release UIButton counter should start counting down from the last value to 0 (decrement by 1 in 1 sec).

If I press UIButton again counter should start counting up.

Comment: ... and register for touch down and both touch up events on the button to decide when to start your phases of operation. The default wiring to a button to perform an action is touch up inside but `UIControl`s can post every type of control event as per  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events @RASS I think you should probably promote your comment to an answer, by the way. Then I can move this comment to your answer.

Comment: @Tommy, I just promoted it.

Answer (score 1):

You quite clearly need to write your own algorithms to manage this task. You can use `NSTimer` to handle the time constraints e.g. `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInt target:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]`.

I would suggest dividing the time by the number of increments e.g. `2/50` will get you the pause needed between each increment when counting from 0 to 50. Use your natural programming brain and flair for the rest...

Comment: Be aware that `NSTimer` may not be accurate enough for such a small interval: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737877/how-to-get-a-accurate-timer-in-ios