# How to get NSEvent timestamp in milliseconds?

Tags: macos, cocoa

```
@property(readonly) NSTimeInterval timestamp;
```

denotes the time when the event occurred in seconds since system startup. I want to compare the timestamps of two events but their differences can also be in milliseconds. So, is there any way to get the timestamp of an event in milliseconds. I know I can use the methods mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889380/how-can-i-get-a-precise-time-for-example-in-milliseconds-in-objective-c) question but would that be appropriate to use for events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want milliseconds you can multiply by 1000.0 but you can compare without multiplying. Documentation of `NSTimeInterval`:

> `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`
>
> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.